# Mutation probability on strongly varying chromosome length

Tags: genetic-algorithms

I am working on a Genetic (or rather Memetic) Algorithm for optimizing a scheduling problem.
I have *n* orders to schedule and the solution representation is an array of *n* integers that specify when an order takes place.

Mutation probabilities are typically given as that, probabilities. This however leads to weird (?) behaviours when parameter tuning. A probability of 1% means of course that an individual with 100 orders (so instances of the problem with n=100) has one gene mutated but also, that an individual of an instance with n=200 has two genes mutated. Which in turn means I move more orders around which feels like a larger change to the individual based on the size of the instance.

This feels odd and I am not sure whether that is an actual problem or if it makes more sense to actually make the probability for mutation dependent on n. E.g. I specify mutation-probability of *pm* mutations per chromosome and in the code the the actual percentage is *pm / n*.

So all in all my questions are:

1. Is this actually a non-issue
2. Does the proposed idea of a parameter taking the number of mutations instead of percentage make sense
3. Is there literature about this situation? because I didnt find any and am having a hard time googling something this weirdly specific.

Thanks!